# Automatically save multiple worksheets in separate files

Tags: excel, vba

currently trying to use my attached code to separate the large consolidated file into separate files based on the sheet name.

The macro works when there are fewer sheets in the list (note, the sheet names aren't copied from the actual file).

I get multiple different errors when running this one (currently getting a Syntax Error). I will be copying the code and changing the sheet names for the other 3 individual files.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Here's my code**

```
Sub Divideworksheets ()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim Filepath as String
Dim Newfilename as String
Dim ARR as String

    FilePath = CreateObject("Script.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Sheets(Array(_
    "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3", "Sheet 4", "Sheet 5", "Sheet 6", _
    "Sheet 7", "Sheet 8", "Sheet 9", "Sheet 10", "Sheet 11", "Sheet 12", _
    "Sheet 13", "Sheet 14", "Sheet 15", "Sheet 16", "Sheet 17", "Sheet 18", _
    "Sheet 19", "Sheet 20", "Sheet 21", "Sheet 22", "Sheet 23", "Sheet 24", _
    )).Copy


    newfilename = Range("H1").Value & "File Title.xlsx"

Application.DisplayAlerts = false
    
    With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs FilePath & "\" & newfilename, FileFormat: 51
    .Close 0

    End With 

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Confirmed, no stylized quotes. To double check I copy/pasted the quotes that were being used previously and the errors (not just syntax) still occurred.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding "New", but why does: `.SaveAs FilePath & "\" & new filename, FileFormat: 51` contain the "New"

Comment: Good eye. Just edited to remove the space. The space wasn't there on my macro, just an error when copying over.

Comment: Oh, it's not "New" as in "New Object" it's the new filename. Well I was hoping that was going to solve everything

Comment: So where are these errors, specifically which lines?